# Usng Vue.js to push dynamically created inputs to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

What would the best process be to push dynamically created inputs to an array. Ideally I would like an array in the data like.

```
customer_answers: [1,4,5,6,8]
```

The items in the array being the values of the answers. I understand that each answer would need to be pushed and probably use `on:change` to run a a method.

However how would I identify each question where the questions and answers and dynamic?

The questions code is below:

```
              <div v-for="(question, item) in questions.questions">
                {{question.question}}
                <div v-if="grouped_answers">
                  <div v-for="a in grouped_answers[item].answers">
                    <label>{{a.answer}}</label>
                    <div v-if= "question.type === 'radio'">
                      <input type="radio" v-bind:value="a.id">
                    </div>
                    <div v-if= "question.type === 'checkbox'">
                      <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="a.id">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

The full code if it helps is below:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <div v-for="app in appliances">
                <input type="radio" id="one" v-model="appliance"  v-bind:value="app.id" v-on:change="getQuestions">
                <label for="one">{{app.appliance}}</label>
              </div>
              <br>
              <span>Picked: {{appliance}}</span>
              </br>
              </br>
                <div v-for="co in brands">
                  <input type="radio" id="two" v-model="brand"  v-bind:value="co.id">
                  <label for="one">{{co.brand}}</label>
                </div>
              <span>Picked: {{ brand }}</span>
              </br>
              </br>
                <input type="radio" id="one" value=1 v-model="age">
                <label for="one">1 Year</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="two" value=2 v-model="age">
                <label for="two">2 Years</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="two" value=3 v-model="age">
                <label for="two">3 Years</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="two" value=4 v-model="age">
                <label for="two">4 Years</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="two" value=5 v-model="age">
                <label for="two">5 Years</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="two" value=6 v-model="age">
                <label for="two">6 Years</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="two" value=7+ v-model="age">
                <label for="two">7+ Years</label>
                <br>
              <span>Picked: {{ age }}</span>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div v-for="(question, item) in questions.questions">
                {{question.question}}
                <div v-if="grouped_answers">
                  <div v-for="a in grouped_answers[item].answers">
                    <label>{{a.answer}}</label>
                    <div v-if= "question.type === 'radio'">
                      <input type="radio" v-bind:value="a.id">
                    </div>
                    <div v-if= "question.type === 'checkbox'">
                      <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="a.id">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
                <input v-model="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                <p>First Name is: {{ first_name }}</p>
                <input v-model="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                <p>Last Name is: {{ last_name }}</p>
                <input v-model="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number">
                <p>Phone Number is: {{ phone_number }}</p>
                <input v-model="email" placeholder="Email">
                <p>Email is: {{ email }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
      mounted() {
          console.log('Component ready.');

          console.log(JSON.parse(this.a));
          console.log(JSON.parse(this.b));

          this.appliances = JSON.parse(this.a);
          this.brands = JSON.parse(this.b);

      },

      props: ['a','b'],

        data: function() {
          return {
              appliances: '',
              appliance: '',
              brands: '',
              brand: '',
              age: '',
              first_name: '',
              last_name: '',
              phone_number: '',
              email: '',
              questions: '',
              answers: '',
              result: '',
              grouped_answers:'',
              customer_answers: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
         incrementItem: function(item) {return item + 1},

         getQuestions: function (){
           console.log(this.appliance);
           var self = this;
           axios.get('/get_questions/' + this.appliance, {

            })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                self.questions = response.data;
                self.getAnswers();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
         },
         getAnswers: function (){
           console.log(this.appliance);
           var self = this;
           axios.get('/get_answers/' + this.appliance, {

              })
              .then(function(response) {
                  console.log(response.data);
                  self.answers = response.data;
                  self.putAnswers();
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
              });
         },
         putAnswers: function (){
           var result = {};

           for (var i = 0; i < this.answers.answers.length; i++) {
             var question_id = this.answers.answers[i].question_id;
             console.log(question_id);
             if(!result[question_id]) {
                result[question_id] = {question_id: question_id, answers: []};
              }
              result[question_id].answers.push({
                id: this.answers.answers[i].id,
                question_id: question_id,
                answer: this.answers.answers[i].answer})
           }
           result = Object.keys(result).map(function (key) { return result[key]; });
           console.log(result);

           this.grouped_answers = result;

           console.log(this.grouped_answers[0].answers);

         },
       },
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

```
  nextQuestion: function (){
    this.holding_answers = [];
  },

  saveAnswer (question, groupedAnswerItem, value, type, event) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(type);

    if(type === "radio"){
      this.holding_answers = [];
      this.holding_answers.push(value);
    };

    if(type === "checkbox"){

      this.holding_answers.push(value);
    };
  },



      <div v-for="(question, item) in questions.questions">
        {{question.question}}
        <div v-bind:id="item">
        <div v-if="grouped_answers">
          <div v-for="a in grouped_answers[item].answers">
            <label>{{a.answer}}
            <input @change="saveAnswer(question, grouped_answers[item], a.id, question.type)" :type="question.type" :value="a.id" :name="a.question_id">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <button @click="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply use `on:change="findAnswers"` and then a Javascript event

```
methods: {
    findAnswers: function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    },
}
```

Before pushing to a data array.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes first:

- You can remove the `v-if` for checkbox or radio and use a dynamic type like, `:type="question.type"`
- Try to set the initial data as the possible real type, like `grouped_answers` shouldn't be an Array instead of String ?

Ok, so if I understand correctly, you want to save the the correct answer in the right question ? You should consider use the '@change' or '@click' with a function that gets the data that you need as parameter.

For example:

```
<input @change="saveAnswer(question, grouped_answers[item], a.id)" :type="question.type" :value="a.id">
```

saveAnswer:

```
saveAnswer (question, groupedAnswerItem, value, event) {...}
```

That's a general idea, not the implementation, the point is that you can pass the dynamically data as parameter and change as you want. Usually this is the way to go, pass all the information necessary in your function to achieve the change with that data. Inside the function you have access to your data, that should make things easier.

Comment: I am nearly there, they just arent adding to the array. I have updated my answer with where I am. The reason why I used v-if for the type is because I could use v-model. 

The problem I have using your method is that the data `holding_answers` only updates the first time. I also need different processes for checkboxes and arrays. Is there a way around this. Also on click of the button holding answers needs to be cleared

Comment: You should check the [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection) for array change detection, that might be your problem. It is very hard to point what exactly you want, what is wrong and what you expect, I would suggest to try to explain a bit more so others can understand better.